# record validation message and message box in ms access 2010

Tags: validation, ms-access

Good Morning All,

I'm working on a simple database. I use the validation record where the start date < end date, with a validation message to explain the issue to the user.
Also, I use a button in a form to add new record followed by a confirmation message.
The strange thing is that neither the validation message appear nor the confirmation !!.
In another form, I use the validation message for a field (not record) and confirmation message for adding the record and both of them work fine,

Any suggestions to fix the issue ?!,

Comment: Show the code... Please?

Comment: @MurDeR for the record validation, I used the "field validation" from the menu without using the code. For the confirmation msg box, I used the function Form_AfterInsert with one line code. The same function is used for another form and works fine !!